# Clockwork: error: cannot load 'recovery-clockwork': No error

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, nexus-7, clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot

I am trying to flash a recovery-image file into my Nexus 7 but the flashing fails

know that I am working on windows and my image file is located in the same folder as adb and fastboot files are

here are the steps I am following:

- start the tablet android system, and the device works fine
- I restart the tablet into the bootloader using: **`adb reboot bootloader`**
- browse to the Recovery Mode and then check if the adb sees the tablet: **`fastboot devices`**
- adb is working fine and can detect the device and read its serial number
- then when I flash: **`fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork.img`**: I get this error:

  **`error: cannot load 'recovery-clockwork': No error`**

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just to make sure: the file you are going to flash is named `recovery-clockwork.img`, and located within the same directory you are working from? Have you tried with a full path?

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, it is name is **recovery-clockwork.img**, I removed the version numbers and put it within the same directory I am working from .. but no, did not try the full path yet ..

Comment: @Izzy: yes it works.. the mistake was, after adding the adb path to my environment-settings, I keep opening the cmd and then run the `fastboot flash` command ..  so it was `c:\User\User1` .. now, I change the working directory to the platform-tools folder ..`c:\...\platform-tools` .. and the flash command worked

Comment: OK, I did! Glad it was that easy :) In fact, I didn't expect that, as the error should have been something like "no such file" then...

Comment: @Izzy: me too, was excepting something more complicated, but, luckily, it was not  .. btw, it gives me the error "no such file" when I wrongly state the file name ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common errors (and solutions to them) are:

- different file name: make sure the file is really named `recovery-clockwork.img`, in your example, or adjust your command according to the file name
- wrong path, e.g. your file resides in `C:\Downloads`, but you're executing `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork.img` from `C:\`: Either first change to the directory the `.img` file is located in, move the `.img` to where you want to execute your command, or try specifying the file with its full path (e.g. `C:\Downloads\recovery-clockwork.img`)
- sometimes `adb`/`fastboot` behaves strangely when executed from "somewhere else". In those cases it helps to first changing to the directory where the resp. executable is located, and run your command from there.