# Unable to install Custom Recovery

Tags: rooting

I am unable to install custom recovery on my phone. I am following these instructions : http://www.informationlord.com/root-micromax-canvas-a1/. Every time I try to do it i get the following error:

error: cannot load recovery.img
Please help.
P.S. I have enabled USB debugging and successfully unlocked bootloader.

After many attempts, I got this in my last attempt.

[image]

When I try to get into the custom recovery, it always takes me to Android System Recovery instead of Philz.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53971/clockwork-error-cannot-load-recovery-clockwork-no-error

Comment: @Firelord: This article contains the link for installing custom recovery too.

Answer (score 0):

When you are all rooted and unlocked install minimal adb and fastboot, then connect your phone. Open the winshell and type

```
adb devices
```

to check, if you are properly connected. Adb's output should be your phone ID. Then make sure you have the boot.img placed in your adb folder then type

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

EDIT:

Grant superuser-access and wait. Then try to boot in recovery.

Then you should load Framaroot http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276 to your phone and start with choosing aragiorn This should root phone and install supersu. After doing that unlock your bootloader and flash recovery. When you use Windows 8 try to reboot holding shift, choose the problem related menu entry and reboot. Then choose option 7 (will turn off driver signature) reinstall driver and try again.

Had the same issue with my adb and phone driver (xperia z2) on my windows 8 machine.

Comment: Did you see the link that OP mentioned? It's about rooting. The link assumes that boot-loader is unlocked and recovery is flashed with custom one, so that supersu.zip can be flashed via recovery. How come then OP would be able to follow your answer(I wonder)? You did mention the point about which I agree but the beginning assumes something which OP is unable to achieve.

Comment: But as he says in the beginning of the post he successfully unlocked bootloader, what means he has to be root on his phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your phone again reflashes the stock recovery on reboot.So after flashing philz, **

> just boot into recovery without booting into os

** and then flash the root file.